# How is malicious code executed on android devices without owners' knowledge?

Tags: buffer-overflow, steganography, voip, remote-code-execution

1. I was wondering how hackers were able to gain remote access to one's android device with the help of just a .PNG file. This vulnerability was announced by Google but they didn't provide much information about how it works. I want to know how the malicious code inside the .PNG gets executed without the user installing any application whatsoever. Metasploit payload embedded into .PNG file?
2. Also, there's this recent WhatsApp VoIP vulnerability which allowed attackers to remotely install a spyware developed by the Israeli Hacking Firm NSO Group on the target's device with just a WhatsApp phone call. Attackers were then able to execute code remotely on the victim's device. From the research I made, they said that specially crafted VoIP packets were sent to the target. This led me wondering how packets could cause a buffer overflow and install the spyware without the target's knowledge.
   Is it about shellcode? netcat? ssh?

I'm really willing to learn how it works at the core and I need someone to sort of clarify how things like this happen.

Comment: There is a detailed description for how the WhatsApp vulnerability worked at [How a double-free bug in WhatsApp turns to RCE](https://awakened1712.github.io/hacking/hacking-whatsapp-gif-rce/). And there are more details [here](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/47515).

Comment: I was talking about the Pegasus Spyware one.. Anyways, thanks.